# Stacked barplot using R base: how to add values inside each stacked bar

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I found a plot in a stats book, which I want to reproduce with the base package.

The plot looks like this:

[image]

So far I have the plot, but I have problems to add a centred labels to each part of the bar.

My code looks like this:

```
data   <- sample( 5, 10 , replace = TRUE )

colors <- c('yellow','violet','green','pink','red')

relative.frequencies <- as.matrix( prop.table( table( data ) ) )

bc <- barplot( relative.frequencies, horiz = TRUE, axes = FALSE, col = colors )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your given example, we can do (**all readers can skip this part and jump to the next**):

```
set.seed(0)  ## `set.seed` for reproducibility
dat <- sample( 5, 10 , replace = TRUE )
colors <- c('yellow','violet','green','pink')
h <- as.matrix( prop.table( table( dat ) ) )
## compute x-location of the centre of each bar
H <- apply(h, 2L, cumsum) - h / 2
## add text to barplot
bc <- barplot(h, horiz = TRUE, axes = FALSE, col = colors )
text(H, bc, labels = paste0(100 * h, "%"))
```

[image: strip]

---

## For all readers

**I will now construct a comprehensive example for you to digest the idea.**

**Step 1: generate a toy matrix of percentage for experiment**

```
## a function to generate `n * p` matrix `h`, with `h > 0` and `colSums(h) = 1`
sim <- function (n, p) {
  set.seed(0)
  ## a positive random matrix of 4 rows and 3 columns
  h <- matrix(runif(n * p), nrow = n)
  ## rescale columns of `h` so that `colSums(h)` is 1
  h <- h / rep(colSums(h), each = n)
  ## For neatness we round `h` up to 2 decimals
  h <- round(h, 2L)
  ## but then `colSums(h)` is not 1 again
  ## no worry, we simply reset the last row:
  h[n, ] <- 1 - colSums(h[-n, ])
  ## now return this good toy matrix
  h
  }

h <- sim(4, 3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 0.43 0.31 0.42
#[2,] 0.13 0.07 0.40
#[3,] 0.18 0.30 0.04
#[4,] 0.26 0.32 0.14
```

**Step 2: understand a stacked bar-chart and get "mid-height" of each stacked bar**

For stacked bar-chart, the height of the bar is the cumulative sum of each column of `h`:

```
H <- apply(h, 2L, cumsum)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 0.43 0.31 0.42
#[2,] 0.56 0.38 0.82
#[3,] 0.74 0.68 0.86
#[4,] 1.00 1.00 1.00
```

We now shift back `h / 2` to get the mid / centre of each stacked bar:

```
H <- H - h / 2
#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 0.215 0.155 0.21
#[2,] 0.495 0.345 0.62
#[3,] 0.650 0.530 0.84
#[4,] 0.870 0.840 0.93
```

**Step 3: producing a bar-chart with filled numbers**

For a vertical bar-chart, `H` above gives the `y` coordinate of the centre of each stacked bar. The `x` coordinate is returned by `barplot` (invisibly). Be aware, that we need to **replicate** each of `x`'s element `nrow(H)` times when using `text`:

```
x <- barplot(h, col = 1 + 1:nrow(h), yaxt = "n")
text(rep(x, each = nrow(H)), H, labels = paste0(100 * h, "%"))
```

[image: vertical barchart]

For a horizontal bar-chart, `H` above gives the `x` coordinate of the centre of each stacked bar. The `y` coordinate is returned by `barplot` (invisibly). Be aware, that we need to **replicate** each of `y`'s element `nrow(H)` times when using `text`:

```
y <- barplot(h, col = 1 + 1:nrow(h), xaxt = "n", horiz = TRUE)
text(H, rep(y, each = nrow(H)), labels = paste0(100 * h, "%"))
```

[image: Horizontal bar-chart]

Comment: Wow you are fast. Good answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using `mapply`:

```
invisible(mapply(function(k, l) text(x = (k - l/2), y = bc, 
          labels = paste0(l*100, "%"), cex = 1.5),
          cumsum(relative.frequencies), relative.frequencies))
```

`mapply` is a multivariate version of `sapply`. In this case, it takes two inputs: `cumsum(relative.frequencies)` and `relative.frequencies` and applies the `text()` function using those two vectors. `x =` is the coordinates of the labels which takes each cumulative sum minus half of each corresponding `relative.frequencies`. `relative.frequencies` is then used again as the labels to be plotted.

The `invisible()` function suppresses the printing of outputs into the console.

[image]